# Mysterious letters appearing at the top of a few pages

Tags: php, html

I have just taken over a wordpress site. On most of the pages the letters "de" appear at the very top - totally unrelated to the content of the page. When I look at the source of these different pages I see that these pages start with "de" and then the actual markup begins.

For example:

```
de<br/>
```

or

```
de<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any ideas where to look for where this code is coming from? Looking at the URLs I have tried admin.php and index.php but beyond that I'm stumped.

Comment: Are those pages using a different page template?  In the editor, you can check under "Page Attributes"

Comment: Or based on the text "de", maybe it's a translation plugin.

Comment: I notice now it's on more than just 2 pages. So I've corrected that in my question. I don't have a translation plugin - everything is English

Comment: Where do I find "Page Attributes" ?

Comment: Oh, I happen to have stumbled upon Page Attributes. I don't see a different template... it's template is itself

Comment: If you open the page in the editor, you'll see it on the right side.  There's a screenshot of it here:  https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/

Comment: Is it "Default Template"?

Comment: well it's the name of the page itself. Contact Us for example

Comment: I lie. It says Contact Page - the page itself is Contact Us.

Comment: I think that has something to do with using Visual Composer plugin, no?

Comment: Okay, in that case, I would look for the Contact Page page template.  Probably in a "templates" folder in the theme files

Comment: It could be Visual Composer, but I would first check for any custom page templates in the theme files.

Comment: ok so the two letters now appear even on the login page. they're everywhere across the whole site... any ideas?

Comment: Have you double checked the Visual Composer settings for any global JavaScript?  https://visualcomposer.com/help/settings/custom-css/